# add else conditional to simplified structure block

Tags: python

Good morning,
I have an if for code to which I want to add an else statement, but it is giving me an error.
How could I do it.
Thanks a lot.

code to which I want to add the: `if line_tax.price_include`
equivalent to code (b)

```
self.total_des = sum([
     line.price_unit2*line.quantity for line in self.invoice_line_ids 
     if len([line.price_unit2*line.quantity for line_tax in line.invoice_line_tax_ids if line_tax.tipo.code in ["A"]] )
])
```

code (b):

```
self.total_des=0
for line in self.invoice_line_ids:
    for line_tax in line.invoice_line_tax_ids:
        if line_tax.tipo in ["A"]:
            if line_tax.price_include: 
                self.total_des=self.total_des+line.price_unit2*line.quantity
            else:
                self.total_des=self.total_des+line.price_unit2*line.quantity*-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the conditions

- `if line_tax.tipo in ["A"]` is here to include whether or not the value in the `sum`
- `if line_tax.price_include` is here to choose between modifier `1` or `-1`

```
self.total_des = sum(line.price_unit2 * line.quantity *(1 if line_tax.price_include else -1) 
                     for line in self.invoice_line_ids 
                     for line_tax in line.invoice_line_tax_ids if line_tax.tipo in ["A"])
```

---

Thought about an an arithmemic way to replace `1 if condition else -1` but performance if not here, about twice longer with the following

```
(condition-0.5)*2

int(True)=1  => 1-0.5=0.5  =>  0.5*2 = 1
int(False)=0 => 0-0.5=-0.5 => -0.5*2 = -1
```

Comment: Sorry, everything is correct. It was a mistake of mine when it came to digital. it is solved as you mention. Thanks a lot.